# Chats JS, horizontal bars?

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm doing some charts, and I went, by the moment, to Chart.js.

The thing is, I would need to make an horizontal bar chart, and I don't see any options to make it.

Is there are way to manage it, or you reccomend me another library to make it?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [jqPlot charts](http://www.jqplot.com) because its totally free and nice and it has [Horizontal chart](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php)

Comment: Looks interesting, will make some testings with it! Thanks